# looping background what do i need to use?

Tags: html, css, loops, animation

hello fellow developers and developers in education.

today i saw this cool effect on this website header 
https://www.premiumsmoking.com/nl/e-sigaret/megatwix.html

the smoke effect that keeps looping i thought was very cool so i tried to remake it,

i tried to do this using css animation but the problem i found was when the div with the 
background was on like 80% you start to see the black space left to the div.

i want to make it that it looks like its an no ending cicle. (maybe something with fadein?)

this is the code i have now

```
.element {
    width:3000px;
    height:1000px;
    background-image:url(moveimage1.png);
    position:relative;
    margin:10px;
    z-index: -1;

animation:myfirst 200s infinite;
}
@keyframes myfirst
   {
0%   {opacity: 0.25; margin-left:  -1500px; }
50%  {opacity: 1;}
100% {opacity: 0.25; margin-left: 1000px; }
}
```

i realy hope someone can help me with this "problem"

(if im doing something wrong in this post im sorry ,first time im asking a question on stack overflow)

already thx for reading my question.

--edit--

For everyone that also wants to use this this is my final code :

```
.element {
    width:100%;
    height:1000px;
    background-image:url(moveimage1.png);
    background-size: 3000px 1000px;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    z-index: -1;

animation:myfirst 10s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes myfirst
   {
0%   {opacity: 0.25; background-position:  0; }
50%  {opacity: 1;}
100% {opacity: 0.25; background-position: 3000px; }
}
```

Much thanx for loki

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but they use two images...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to move the block, not the background inside it. I suggest animating `background-position` property, not `margin-left`. You won't have any black space anymore as long as your background image repeats

Comment: More generally, there's no substitute for checking what they're doing yourself. Grab Firebug and pull apart their markup + CSS and you'll be able to see just how it works.

Comment: thanx for this quick answer ! finally working now after 2 hours haha

got one problem left tho, it seems to slow down near the end of the animation is done
are there any fixes for this ?

Comment: @jurjen there is: `animation-timing-function: linear`

Comment: @jurjen sorry, forgot you've used the shorthand definition. just add `linear` as the last argument to the line `animation:myfirst 200s infinite;`

Comment: thanx alot realy appreciate it !